# Intel 6300 wireless card won't work on CentOS 7 - worked during install though!

Tags: centos, wifi, hardware

I installed centos 7 on a laptop with an intel 6300 wireless card in it.

During the install, the wireless card was available and I was able to connect to my lan.

After the install, I don't see the card in the network settings.
lspci shows it is there.

`03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 [8086:422b] (rev 35)`

How can I get centos 7 to recognize it?

edit:  I see also that centos has the right firmware for this device in /lib/firmware (cross referenced with the intel website)

edit 2:  this command is showing it there as a device.  How do I get it from the unmanaged state?

```
[root@localhost network-scripts]# nmcli d
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
virbr0      bridge    connected  virbr0     
em1         ethernet  connected  em1        
virbr0-nic  tap       connected  virbr0-nic 
lo          loopback  unmanaged  --         
wlp3s0      wifi      unmanaged  --
```

Comment: @don_crissti a dell precision m4700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ran `yum install NetworkManager-wifi` and rebooted and my wifi card showed up.

was able to connect - posting this answer from that connection :)